# Find variable "a" in a variable "b" that contains a list - Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to find variable "A" in a variable "B" containing a list (in the Django template)?
At the moment im trying to acomplish this within a for loop. Unfortunately that does not work.
The variables carries the correct content, ive just checked it.
However the for loop never gives back "true" - although variable A is definitely in the list of variable B

- username.0 = Variable A that contains an integer like: 1 or 7 or 16
- user = Variable B that contains the list in this form: [1,5,6]

  ```
      {% for id, name, user in allowed_user %}
          <tr>
              <td class="align-middle"><strong>{{ name }}</strong></td>
              <td class="align-middle" align="center">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <select multiple class="form-control" id="user_rights">
                          {% for username in alle_user %}
                              {% if username.0 in user %}
                              {{ username.0 }} {{ user }}
                              <option selected="selected">if {{ username.1 }}</option>
                              {% else %}
                              {{ username.0 }} {{ user }}
                              <option>else {{ username.1 }}</option>
                              {% endif %}
                          {% endfor %}
                          </select>
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  ```

Comment: Can you show where you assign the values to username and user?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced problems similar to this, and if you're sure that the value is in the list, often the answer is that you're comparing strings to ints. Try casting both as one or the other before you pass it in to the template to make sure.